# When does a row standardized adjacency matrix have a real spectrum?

Tags: graph-theory, matrices, eigenvalues, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrices

A colleague in spatial statistics was looking at a map with about 600 regions. For the application she's considering, the induced adjacency matrix had some undesirable properties (where two regions are neighbors if they share a border). Instead, she calculated the row-standardized adjacency matrix and somewhat surprisingly, the entire spectrum was real.

I was wondering whether this was to be expected, or if there is something special about the particular example.

Edit: I have edited out the rest of the question, which was trying to understand the probability. The answer explains why this is always the case.

Comment: What's exactly a "row-standardized adjacency matrix"? Is your graph oriented?

Comment: I should have been more clear. It's non-oriented, and you just divide each row of the adjacency matrix by the row sum. This breaks the symmetry, which is how complex eigenvalues can arise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the adjacency matrix is $A,$ the "row-standardized" matrix is $DA$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix all of whose diagonal entries are positive, so has a positive diagonal square root $D^{1/2}$. Now,

$$DA = D^{1/2} D^{1/2} A D^{1/2} D^{-1/2},$$ so your matrix is similar to

$$D^{1/2} A D^{1/2},$$ which is a symmetric matrix, and so has real spectrum.

Comment: Remark: so there is nothing strange about OP's graph like he was suggesting; that property holds for every graph.

Comment: That's very interesting. An immediate consequence is that the eigenvectors are orthogonal, since $D^{1/2}$ is diagonal.